# Distribution of discrete function of continuous random variable?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, transformation

It has been quite some time that I did statistics, and I am not sure how to figure out the distribution of a function of a random variable if the function itself discretizes (if that is a word) the random variable. So I hope you can help me remember / figure out how to solve it.

Let $x$ be a normally distributed random variable. Now, consider the random variable $y = g(x)$, where $g(x) = 1$ if $x \leq a$, $g(x) = 2$ if $a< x \leq b$ and $g(x) = 3$ if $x > b$, and $a,b$ are some constants in $R$.

My goal is to see if the final distribution belongs to the exponential family, and knowing the distribution would be a necessary first step. If the function was continuous, I would know what to do, but I am somewhat stuck since it is not. Any help including links to theorems is appreciated!

Comment: If $F$ denotes the CDF - i.e. the cumulative distribution function -  of $x$ then $P(g(x)=1)=P(x\leq a)=F(a)$, $P(g(x)=2)=P(a<x\leq b)=F(b)-F(a)$ and $P(g(x)=3)=P(x>b)=1-F(b)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot drhab! That was easier than I thought, I actually feel somewhat embarrassed now as I somehow expected an expression with truncated normals given the thresholds, but that does indeed not make much sense. I wonder now if it is possible to show that this belongs or does not belong to the exponential family of distrbutions. If you have any thoughts on this, I would appreciate that. Furthermore, feel free to write your comment as an answer, so that I can upvote and accept it.